# How to setup LUIS for invoice dataextraction

Tags: azure-language-understanding, extract, invoice

Can LUIS be setup to extract invoice data like IBAN, invoice-number, invoice-data and amounts from a PDF with OCR-layer?

We are trying to find a way to fase-out some old software we are using to capture document data. I'm looking into LUIS for this. I have already tried to setup a App with LUIS to get data from phrases and that seems to work fine. Now I want try to extract invoice-data from PDF invoices. How would i go about?

I just would like to have some pointers on how to go about creating an working app that can import PDF documents and extract invoice data from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [form recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/)? That sounds like a better fit.